# Why Typescript Intellisense not working in my Repo?(with yarn berry)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarn-berry

Here is my repo, https://github.com/Jowen0/React-TIL/tree/main/react-app-rewired

i want to compile out of src files in my apps

but, i have 2 problems

1. Don't Intellisense React component files
   In my index.tsx, it isn't recognize App.tsx like this:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWT6q.png)
2. Don't Intellisense src external files
   In my App.tsx, it isn't recognize aaa/index.ts like this:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7uYY.png)

How can i fix it? Someone help me about this.